# CRM 2011 - change statecode + statuscode by javascript

Tags: javascript, soap, dynamics-crm-2011

I want to change statecode and statuscode on ribbon button click in CRM 2011.
I have javascript function calling SOAP:

```
if (typeof (Smpl) == "undefined") { Smpl = {}; }

Smpl.Items = {
change: function () {

    var entityId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId().substr(1, 36);
    var entityName = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName();
    var entityState = 0;
    var entityStatus = 100007891;

    var xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" +
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>" +
    "<soap:Body><Execute xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices'><Request xsi:type='SetStateDynamicEntityRequest'>" +
    "<Entity><Id xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2006/CoreTypes'>" + entityId + "</Id>" +
    "<Name xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2006/CoreTypes'>" + entityName + "</Name></Entity>" +
    "<State>" + entityState + "</State>" +
    "<Status>" + entityStatus + "</Status>" +
    "</Request></Execute></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

    var xHReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    xHReq.Open("POST", "http://my.full.com:80/web/mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx", false);
    xHReq.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/Execute");
    xHReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    xHReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", xml.length);
    xHReq.send(xml);

    var resultXml = xHReq.responseXML;
    var errorCount = resultXml.selectNodes('//error').length;
    if (errorCount != 0) {
        var msg = resultXml.selectSingleNode('//description').nodeTypedValue;
        alert(msg);
    }
    window.location.reload();
  }
}
```

I'd say the whole code is okay, but of course, it's not working at all :/
On google I found just a few snippets, but nothing different from my code.
Does not really nobody change status from the ribbon via javascript??

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For changing state of an entity you need to use the EntityMoniker, in .net in plugins and also in JScript.

Try the code from the following link:

[Set Status or State of a Record Using Jscript](http://mileyja.blogspot.com/2011/07/set-status-or-state-of-record-using.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was surfing on the web, because a friend of mine had the same problem, I haven't changed de statecode in CRM 2011 via JScript, but I think I have your solution.

In case of my friend, he had statecode value in wrong format, he was using 0 or 1, and service was returning an error telling him, 0 or 1 weren't correct values of statecode, then I though, coding in C# you have to put in State a value from an Enumeration ('Active' or 'Inactive'), he changed his integer value to 'Active' and the soap call runs fine.

Report the real solution if you arrive to it :)

See you.